# JMeter 5.0: View results in a tree listener shows result of last 100 threads only

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, listener

We executed our scripts with 200 users and saw View results in a tree listener is showing result of only last 100 users? Why is it clearing data automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is regular behavior of JMeter since version 4.0.

View Results Tree previously stored all SamplerResults in memory, so users using GUI mode for load testing would end up with OutOfMemory.

So Jmeter team introduced a new behavior which only keeps a limited number of results and non immediate refresh.

Property which controls this can be modified in user.properties:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous

> view.results.tree.max_results
>         Maximum number of main samples, that should be stored and displayed.
>         A value of 0 will store all results. This might consume a lot of memory.
>         Defaults to: 500

Anyway yoy should never load test in gui mode, use non gui mode and generate the html report using:

> jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l results.csv -e -o report-output-folder